# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages: How to automatically redirect to Login page from Index page?

Tags: razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

I am building a web application using the ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC and Razor pages.

I am new to Razor pages.

I created a basic application using above. I want to load the Login page on start of the application but
the Index.cshtml page seems to be the start page.

To redirect from the Index.cshtml page (start page) to my Login.cshtml page, I did following in the Index.cshtml PageModel. But it is not working.

**EDITED:**

Index.cshtml:

```
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
        <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
        <form method="get" asp-page="Index" hidden name="myForm">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Redirect 1" asp-page-handler="Redirect1" hidden />
        </form>
    </div>
```

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IndexModel() 
        {
          OnPostRedirect1();
        }
        public void OnGet() {}
        public IActionResult OnPostRedirect1()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("Login");
        }        
    }
```

How to automatically redirect to Login page from Index page?

Comment: Please explain "not working". FYI, it's typical to only perform such a redirect if the user isn't currently logged in. Additionally, you would typically have middleware or authorization filters that perform the redirect before the controller method is even hit.

Comment: The Login page was not opening even after executing RedirectToPage("Login");. 

I want the Index page (default start page) to load the Login page automatically after the application runs.. The code RedirectToPage("Login");does not open Login page and the Index remains displayed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes. But I don't know what you're doing wrong because I haven't tested it. I understood what you were asking but I was offering my opinion. Routes that require the user to be logged in should not enforce this requirement in their implementation it should be done before index ever loads if index needs a logged in user. In other words, I was offering security advice.

Comment: If you are using Forms Authentication, I think this would work -> FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage() ;

Comment: I want the Login page to be the start page of the application and not the Index page. When I created a new application, a page "Index" was created automaically. I added new page "Login" later. I added  RedirectToPage("Login") in the post event in the  Index.cshtml.cs page and called it in the IndexModel() constructor. When the application is run, the Index page gets called first.but the post event is not called.

Comment: @devman - What about RedirectToAction("Login","Login");?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some options. If you don't want unauthorised users to visit the Index page, apply the `[Authorize]` attribute to the PageModel class:

```
[Authorize]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    ...
}
```

Then, if your login page is not located at `/account/login`, configure the login page in Startup:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.LoginPath = "/YourLoginPage";
});
```

The framework will automatically redirect unauthenticated users to the login page. This is what most people are likely to do. Or, if you don't want Index at all, remove it and set the login page as the home page by changing its route template:

```
 @page "/"
```

This will override the conventional route for the page, based on its file path: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#override-routes

Comment: Changing the default login path doesn't seem to make any difference for me?

Comment: @SteveSmith Seems like your issue is not the same a the one this answer addressed. I recommend you post a new question providing as much detail as you can.